# Firebase query isn't working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift2, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to check if a username is already taken.

My Database looks like that: 
[image]

That is the query I try to use:

```
var returning = true
        print("test101")

        ref.child("users")
            .queryOrderedByChild("name")
            .observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in

                print("test102")
                if let nname = snapshot.value!["name"] as? String{
                    if self.nicknameTextField.text! == nname{
                        returning = false
                    }
                    print(returning)

                }
            })
```

My problem is that the Compiler doesn't go into the nested function and I don't understand why?
The Console prints "test101" but not "test102"

Comment: Sounds like a permission issue. Try setting  `FIRDatabase.setLoggingEnabled(true)` and se what it says

Comment: Good call @Chris. If that is the case, have a look at the first blue box on the  [page about reading data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/retrieve-data).

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget:

> To read or write data from the database, you need an instance of FIRDatabaseReference:

```
var ref: DatabaseReference!
ref = Database.database().reference()
```

Comment: Of course I have this statement. This wasn't my question